# Android animation white patch

Tags: android, android-animation

Android activity has a white patch on top and bottom which is visible during animation. How to I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

What you are likely seeing is the background of the activity before your activity inflates overlapping components; those cannot be drawn until the layout is inflated.

You could consider adapting the window's background to better reflect it's contents, as described in [this insightful article by Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/).